# Process REST request based on the type of MIME Type

Tags: java, rest, post, jersey, mime-types

I've a method called createCustomer(),it is a POST method and it consumes both MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, now I want to check the actual MIME type of the request that came from client, it can be XML or JSON and based on the request's MIME type I want to call two different methods.

Can you please provide me the code to check the MIME type of the Incoming request and based on  the type call two different methods.

The sample code looks like below:

```
@POST
@Path("/createCustomer")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response createCustomer(Customer customer ) {
    //if the request is in JSON then call the method createCustomerJSON()
    //else if the request is in XML then call the method createCustomerXML()

    //String output = output from either the method createCustomerJSON() or createCustomerXML()

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it would have been great to have posted some code.

Secondly, one solution would be to create two methods with the same path, one consuming XML and one consuming JSON.

```
@POST
@Path("yourPath")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
public Response createCustomerXML() {...}

@POST
@Path("yourPath")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
public Response createCustomerJSON() {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

[javax.ws.rs.Consumes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Consumes.html) annotation is probably what you need. By putting different annotations on different methods you can split handling of XML and JSON.

From javadoc:

> Defines the media types that the methods of a resource class or MessageBodyReader can accept. If not specified, a container will assume that any media type is acceptable. Method level annotations override a class level annotation. A container is responsible for ensuring that the method invoked is capable of consuming the media type of the HTTP request entity body. If no such method is available the container must respond with a HTTP "415 Unsupported Media Type" as specified by RFC 2616.